# How to use the "feel" of Marvel and DC cinematic fight scenes?

Tags: fiction, script, combat

I want to write a fight scene like the MCU Hulk's fight scene with Iron Man or the DCEU Superman vs Zod fight in *Man of Steel*. I want to have the same general feel, or quality to the fight scene. I am not, however, asking to make a duplicate. I would just like to get the general feel, and duplicate the quality that makes the younger audience like it so much.

### The Question:

How do I identify and duplicate the general feel or quality of those fights and apply it into my own fight scenes? I would like to use the quality that makes those fights enjoyable to a younger audience. I can't tell if it is the speed, the shaky camera, the emotion, or whatnot that makes it the way it is. I would like to identify it so I can use it in my own fights.

A side note: I specifically want to apply this in a superhero one shot film and short story application for teenagers. Powerful superpowers are a necessary requirement.

Comment: Are you writing a script for a film?  Or a scene in a book/novel/written story?  Or a page in a comic book?

Comment: @hszmv a script for a film, but that hopefully could be formatted into a book as well.

Comment: Not a comic book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write the book first because the action you want to covey is limited by your ability to describe, not the budget of the effects for a script.  Having written many superhero fight scenes for personal projects, I've found that the general rule for righting fast paced actions is to keep your sentences as short as possible and don't dwell on describing the action too much in one sentence.  Try to have each sentence describe one piece of a complex movement and remember, dialog is a type of action.  Try not to describe action that occurs after a dialog before the dialog is said.

A complex action should be contained to one paragraph.  When describe an Archeologist getting out of the ancient temple as the stone door slowly close, everything there is a single paragraph (The run to gain speed, the slide to carry the momentum while getting low to clear the door, the roll under the door once there, the hat falling off, the recovery from the roll once cleared the door, the reach for the hat and the last second pull of the iconic costume piece before the loud slam of the heavy stone door).  Hell this could be drawn out by splitting into two separate paragraphs the first about the hero getting through the door, while the later is devoted to the realization of the missing hat and it's recovery.

The net result is because the actions are described in simple, basic, and easy to read sentences, the totality of all actions are described to a complicated degree and read as happening a lot faster and more dynamic than if you described the scene in a single sentence.).

A good way to practice this is to watch a clip of bullet time in an action movie and write down the sequence of events.  It helps that bullet time is commonly used in most modern action films to demonstrate the impressive speed of the stunts reaction (and is hilarious in comedies for the fact that bullet time often shows rather silly looking deformations of the face that you don't see at normal speeds.).

In film bullet time sacrafices run time for attention to detail which is why it's only done for a portion of the fight, but since everyone reads at different speeds, the "run time" of a book isn't impacted if everything is described in bullet time like detail.

Writing these in script is a little less fun because, depending on the scale of the production, typically details of fight scene choreography are not the writers' primary concern as the dialog, stage directions, and description of characters are more their concern.  It's the director who has to translate the basics of the scene into the overall visual aspect of the fight.  You can be detailed but it should be concerned with making sure all the pieces of the fight end up where they need to be at the end of the fight scene.  There is also some control over how the scene is ended, since you might have dialog or stage direction that sets up the victory move (such as a Chekov's Gun) or refers to it (the side kick geeking out about the quick thinking).

When it comes time to shoot the film, normally the choeography is discussed with story boards which are hand drawn still images that show critical moments, the relationship the actors and props are arranged in relationship to the camera angle, and motion of those things between or during scenes, and snippets of dialog to tie the scene to moments in the script.  One of the reasons Hollywood has moved to adapting comicbook characters to film is because Comic Books are nothing more than high quality storyboards (Aside from the major story changes, Watchmen is Largely beat for beat a remake of the Graphic novel... most scenes are filmed to look like individual panels.  And if you like watching videos of Easter Eggs in superhero films, be ready for the host to show a still from the film next to an identical page of comic that inspired the shot, even if it's not from that storyline (The scene in Captain America: Civil War where Cap is using his shield to deflect Iron Man's Uni-beam blast is based off of Iconic Art from the comicbook miniseries the story is loosely adapting to film.).

From there, the action is choregraphed with the stunts and effects teams based on the needs of practical and CGI effects.  The reason for this is that most modern scenes have a little bit of both and the actors may not need to know what order the particular stunt takes place in, but they do need to be instructed where to look if their opponent is going to be composited in in post and practical effects require careful instructions because of safety concerns.  Worst still, some of the best effects can only be done in one take so it requires all of the cast to know what to do before it's done for real.

Edit:

Additional per comments:  It's largely to do with both works having characters that rarely could be rarely seen in real life action for decades until the past few years.  Remember the first Chris Reeves marketed itself with the phrase "You will believe a man can fly" because up until that point, Superman's flying effects were not convincing in live action features (The last one prior to Chris Reeves was the George Reeves TV series.  Here the rig used to show Reeves Flying was so uncomfortable, that Reeves refused to ever film a flying scene again.  For the rest of the show's run, Superman was shown landing or taking off, but never flying on camera.).  The fight scenes in all of Chris Reeves films are nothing special, but the flying still holds up as some good work.

Unfortunately I don't think there is a winning formula for superhero fights that applies to Marvel and DC films fight scenes exclusively.  Personally I like seeing the way the heroes use their environment in the fight, but the lack of that doesn't mean it's bad.  Endgame was a dust covered featureless field with scattered rubble... but that didn't mean it wasn't one of the better fight sequences... compared to the Superman v. Zod fight which had largely the same thing but failed to personally impress (I've seen better animated Superman fights.).

One constant, at least for Marvel, is Marvel characters are at least somewhat aware of how bizarre the fights can get sometime and acknowledge the bizarre conditions, though this is typical Marvel humor which is found in non-action sequences (The first Iron Man was kind of a game changer in that it showed that you could tell a serious superhero story grounded in reality but still have some fun... compared to the trend at the time, where everyone was trying to tell a realistic superhero setting.  The first X-Men film openly mocked the idea of any superhero wearing a colorful costume.  Iron Man suggested that his suit be red and gold for no other reason other than "It'll match my Hot Rod!").

One of the MCU secrets that you might want to look at is gets tapped to direct Marvel films.  The vast majority of the directors in Marvel films are not first time directors and aren't unknown in the industry... but most of their works are not known for action films... most have next to no experience in the genre.   Joss Whedon (Avengers 1 and 2) had some experience with the genre and sci-fi as well, but his were never summer block buster levels of big and he was more known for television than film (not that he didn't do film).   The Russo Brothers (2 Captain America films and 2 Avengers Films) were mostly known for Comedy works and had never done action films.  This means that while they aren't the go to picks of the genres, they also don't aren't in a point where they have styles of shooting action films Look, Just to show my critique isn't coming from a place of artsy superiority, I got nothing against Michael Bay as a director.  The man ain't gonna direct the next Citizen Kane, I'm not going to try and argue that, but if I want to watch a film that requires me to do little thinking about the meaning of the plot, has an awesome car chase with an explosive ending, all I'm saying is the dude delivers for that niche.  But even then, there comes a time where people who do one thing well aren't able to see the angle that a new person can to bring an interesting spin to the genre.

What's more, is that with Marvel films at least (D.C. hasn't gotten this down yet.  Giving Superman to the same guy who did the Dark Knight films is not a winning combination... your just making Batman in a blue and red suit.) are not Superhero films... they're genre films with a superhero in it.  Iron Man films were tech thrillers.  Captain America was a WWII period piece that was retooled into a spy thriller.  Thor was a high fantasy while Dr. Strange is Urban Fantasy.  Guardians of the Galaxy is Space Opera.  Antman is a Heist film.  Spider-Man is a teen comedy.  And the Avengers was just the delivery of a promise that many at the time were skeptical (I remember the pre-Avengers years of superhero films.  The idea of a superhero team film was a fan dream and one that was complicated.  Marvel sold film rights to most of their big ticket names making it unlikely we'd see team ups and DC couldn't make a decent film unless there was a man dressed like a Bat in in it (If it seems like I'm hating on D.C. I'm not.  Superman is hands down my favorite Superhero for reasons I don't care to discuss here.  I don't hate DC for it's Batman focus... I'm just disappointed that in almost 20 years of modern films, they can't make a film that isn't gritty like Batman...).  So each time you watch a Marvel film, you're not watching the same old tropes play out... which is why you can't pin down the fight's winning formula... because the films are vastly different from one another and if you don't like that style of film... well... they can almost be assured they got the superhero film that you do want to see.

Comment: I understand the process for writing a fight scene (I too have written some in the past) but I was asking specifically about the "feel" of the Marvel and DC ones. I was asking for what makes the Marvel and DC ones uniques; what makes them loved by fans so that I can add those elements in my own works. Basically, I was asking for why the Marvel and DC fight scenes are liked by many fans. I wasn't really asking for an overall process.

Comment: I wasn't asking simply "how do I write a fight scene" I was asking "what makes the Marvel and DC ones good so I can apply that to my own works."

Comment: This works well now, thank you.